# ../ method on calling file from root folder cause dropdown wont display i on IE8

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, internet-explorer, directory

Helo guys.I have a website that run smoothly on localhost in Chrome, Firefox and IE8. However the website does not implement SEO, especially the URL. I wanted to practice SEO by categorize the URL and remove .php extension from it.The URL of my website is something like this; localhost/alarm_A16GSM.php. In order for me to categorized the URL i rename the alarm_A16GSM.php file to overview. php and put it in folders. My folder structure looks like something like this.

- alarm-system

  - A16GSM

    - overview.php

Thus, my new URL would be something like localhost/alarm-system/A16GSM/overview.php. In order for me to include header which is in templates folder I use `../` method. I use the same method to call upon my css file. For removing the .php extension, I create .htaccess file and put this code inside it.

[image]

And my new URL works fine on localhost for Chrome and Firefox except for IE8. My drop down menu seems not working properly as it lines on the left side of the page. I wonder why is this happening. Is that because of the `../` method or what.Please help me. You can check my css from here ;

http://jsfiddle.net/9UHcb/

http://jsfiddle.net/bvTzu/
http://jsfiddle.net/frr8d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ive found the solution. Use HTML5 Shim.

To use HTML5 Shim, you just need to add the following within your page's  below all your CSS declarations:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->>
```

for further explanation [click here](http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/semantics.html#unknown-elements)

Answer (score 0):

add to ur css

```
ul li {list-style: none;}
```

and

```
ul {list-style: none;}
```

if this does not work . share ur css code .

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the head section if something does not work in IE10 but it does in other browsers.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ul,ul li {
list-style: none;
float:left;
    }
```

i hope that's working for you, for more help please provide jsfiddle link.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle please?